# send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, lets-encrypt

Because of SSL stalping errors I had to set

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
resolver 127.0.0.1;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
```

But since then I’ve been hit with this error

```
send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Use the correct IP address of your nameserver.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi**

Had a same fresh error in my nginx error.log

2019/04/16 14:18:49 [error] 16988#0: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53

For me helped below 
Check first your **DNS Nameservers**.

My example is for dns resolver godaddy. 
     with:

ns47.domaincontrol.com

ns48.domaincontrol.com

Make an nslookup for these domains and you will get two IP-s. 
Update your /etc/resolv.conf with given nslookup in domain:

- search domaincontrol.com
- nameserver 97.74.103.24
- nameserver 173.201.71.24

Save file, restart nginx and wait few sec. 
My error message dissapeared from logs. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: On AWS, the problem was resolved when I added the nameserver available in `/etc/resolv.conf` as the first priority (leaving the previously added `8.8.x.x` Google nameservers as secondary/tertiary fallbacks)